# Rails server on windows using Vagrant: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/<myapp>/. in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, vagrant

I would not want to make a new post, but the articles I read did not resolve my issue

I'm on Windows 7, and I installed Vagrant on my machine

I created the "appexample", with `rails new appexample` command...

With `rails s` command, this error happens:

```
/home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/appexample/. in PATH, mode 040777

/home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/appexample/. in PATH, mode 040777
```

What prevents me from running the application at the address `localhost:3000`

I've tried all these commands:

```
chmod, sudo chmod , 111,666,775,777, -Rf
```

and nothing works.

Comment: where you run the rails command? from vagrant instance or from windows 7?

Comment: And the error is in Vagrant instance, you need login `vagrant ssh` and change the permission (for example 0755) on /vagrant/<myapp>/

Comment: My operating system is Windows 7.
My virtual machine is Ubuntu.
Access by Vagrant.
I need to use a program called Putty for SSH access

Comment: In vagrant, you can login vagrant instance from `vagrant ssh` directly.